# Data picker no function in the bootstrap modal

Tags: html, datepicker, bootstrap-modal

I used the date picker for show date in modal box but text field not show date picker function. I tried text field without popup, it can work. If inside the modal box, data picker no function in the text field. How to fix date picker in popup modal? Hope someone can guide me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Below is my coding

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label for="cp1" class="control-label col-lg-4">Effective date:</label>
<div class="col-lg-5">
<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="date_borrowed" name="date_borrowed" title="date_borrowed" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" readonly>            
<input type="hidden" class="form-control blank" id="id" name="id"  value="<?php echo md5($rs_wtp['id'] . $md5) ?>">
</div>
</div>
```

[image: Output 2]

If outside the modal box, it can work like below the picture:

[image: Output 3]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code with bootstrap 4.5.0 and bootstrap-datepicker 1.9.0, the datepicker is functioning well in the modal.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-siyOpF/pBWUPgIcQi17TLBkjvNgNQArcmwJB8YvkAgg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-bqVeqGdJ7h/lYPq6xrPv/YGzMEb6dNxlfiTUHSgRCp8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="cp1" class="control-label col-lg-4">Effective date:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="date_borrowed" name="date_borrowed" title="date_borrowed" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" readonly>
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control blank" id="id" name="id" value="<?php echo md5($rs_wtp['id'] . $md5) ?>">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```